Google cloud scheduler http post error 415 FAILED_PRECONDITION
I have created an ASP.NET Core Web API. The method in the API controller is decorated like this:
[HttpPost]
public async Task Post([FromBody] string value)

Then I scheduled a job from google cloud scheduler to call this job with OIDC token for auth. Problem is, it's returning 415 FAILED_PRECONDITION error every time.
I tried invoking the published job (in the server) with fake auth header from postman and it's throwing error as expected that the token is not formatted correctly. However, google scheduler is not even hitting the endpoint because I have step by step logging inside the task.
I was verifying the token like below
string token = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Remove(0, 7); //remove Bearer 
var payload = await VerifyGoogleTokenId(token);

private async Task<GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload> VerifyGoogleTokenId(string token){
GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload payload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(token);
}

Interestingly, when I removed the token checking, i.e. commented below line and used a random string in the value field of the request body - google is reaching the endpoint and invoking the job.
string token = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Remove(0, 7)

Note that above line is inside try catch block so any error will be logged, just in case.
So my questions are:

Can I see the raw log of the http request google is sending?
What am I missing so that google is not even reaching the endpoint?


Your question is missing useful details: (1) the command you used to create cloud scheduler job (gcloud scheduler jobs create http ...) particularly to show whether it's configured to send an access or ID token; (2) where/how the server is deployed; (3) the exact Postman command; (4) the Cloud Scheduler logs (cloudscheduler.googleapis.com%2Fexecutions). The Cloud Scheduler logs don't include the full requests (unfortunately) but you can use a general-purpose HTTP testing site or create a simple test server that dumps the request. HTTP 415 is unsupported media not failed precondition

If you have gcloud installed, you can also test your endpoint using curl --request POST --header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" https://...
